# Kotlin Exposed, avoid multiple queries using DAO

Tags: mysql, sql, kotlin, orm, dao

I've configured my Exposed ORM and DAO classes like this.

```kotlin
object Highlights: IntIdTable("Highlights") {
    val video = reference("videoId", Videos)
    val preview = reference("previewId", Files)
    val title = varchar("title", 255).nullable()
    val createdAt = datetime("createdAt").nullable()
    val createdBy = integer("createdBy").nullable()
    val updatedAt = datetime("updatedAt").nullable()
    val updatedBy = integer("updatedBy").nullable()
    val deletedAt = datetime("deletedAt").nullable()
    val deletedBy = integer("deletedBy").nullable()
    val active = bool("active").nullable()
    val empty = bool("empty").nullable()

    val matchId = reference("matchId", Matches)
    val homeTeamId = reference("homeTeamId", Teams)
    val awayTeamId = reference("awayTeamId", Teams)
    val homeScore = integer("homeScore").nullable()
    val awayScore = integer("awayScore").nullable()
}

class HighlightDAO(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<HighlightDAO>(Highlights)
    val video by VideoDAO referencedOn Highlights.video
    val preview by FileDAO referencedOn Highlights.preview
    val title by Highlights.title
    var createdAt by Highlights.createdAt
    var match  by MatchDAO referencedOn Highlights.matchId

    var players by PlayerDAO via HighlightsPlayers
    val events by HighlightEventDAO referrersOn HighlightEvents.highlightId

    val homeScore by Highlights.homeScore
    val awayScore by Highlights.awayScore
    val empty by Highlights.empty
}
```

It contains references to other ORM and DAO similar to this one.
The problem comes when I try to perform a query.

```kotlin
...

HighlightDAO.findById(highlightId)
...
```

The result is perfectly OK, but Exposed performs a huge number of SELECT queries. Here are the logs.

```
SQL: SELECT Highlights.id, Highlights.videoId, Highlights.previewId, Highlights.title, Highlights.createdAt, Highlights.createdBy, Highlights.updatedAt, Highlights.updatedBy, Highlights.deletedAt, Highlights.deletedBy, Highlights.active, Highlights.empty, Highlights.matchId, Highlights.homeTeamId, Highlights.awayTeamId, Highlights.homeScore, Highlights.awayScore FROM Highlights WHERE Highlights.id = 6657
SQL: SELECT Highlights_Events.id, Highlights_Events.highlightId, Highlights_Events.playerId, Highlights_Events.teamId, Highlights_Events.matchId, Highlights_Events.homeTeamId, Highlights_Events.awayTeamId, Highlights_Events.`name`, Highlights_Events.nameId, Highlights_Events.actionId, Highlights_Events.standartId, Highlights_Events.matchSecond, Highlights_Events.matchPeriod, Highlights_Events.`second` FROM Highlights_Events WHERE Highlights_Events.highlightId = 6657
SQL: SELECT Matches.id, Matches.homeTeamId, Matches.awayTeamId, Matches.competitionSeasonId, Matches.turnId, Matches.GroupId, Matches.createdAt, Matches.createdBy, Matches.updatedAt, Matches.updatedBy, Matches.deletedAt, Matches.deletedBy, Matches.active FROM Matches WHERE Matches.id = 3115
SQL: SELECT Players.id, Players.createdAt, Players.createdBy, Players.updatedAt, Players.updatedBy, Players.deletedAt, Players.deletedBy, Players.active, Highlights_Players.id, Highlights_Players.playerId, Highlights_Players.highlightId FROM Players INNER JOIN Highlights_Players ON Highlights_Players.playerId = Players.id WHERE Highlights_Players.highlightId = 6657
SQL: SELECT Highlights_Events.id, Highlights_Events.highlightId, Highlights_Events.playerId, Highlights_Events.teamId, Highlights_Events.matchId, Highlights_Events.homeTeamId, Highlights_Events.awayTeamId, Highlights_Events.`name`, Highlights_Events.nameId, Highlights_Events.actionId, Highlights_Events.standartId, Highlights_Events.matchSecond, Highlights_Events.matchPeriod, Highlights_Events.`second` FROM Highlights_Events WHERE Highlights_Events.highlightId = 6657
SQL: SELECT Player_details.id, Player_details.playerId, Player_details.shortNameId, Player_details.firstNameId, Player_details.middleNameId, Player_details.lastNameId, Player_details.gender, Player_details.birthDate, Player_details.birthCityId, Player_details.height, Player_details.weight, Player_details.foot, Player_details.`role`, Player_details.status, Player_details.createdAt, Player_details.createdBy, Player_details.updatedAt, Player_details.updatedBy, Player_details.deletedAt, Player_details.deletedBy, Player_details.imageId, Player_details.active FROM Player_details WHERE Player_details.playerId IN (1193, 1246, 2454, 2458, 2536, 2552, 791)
SQL: SELECT Videos.id, Videos.`path`, Videos.pathWasabi, Videos.mimeType, Videos.createdAt, Videos.createdBy, Videos.updatedAt, Videos.updatedBy, Videos.deletedAt, Videos.deletedBy, Videos.active FROM Videos WHERE Videos.id = 25584
SQL: SELECT Images.id, Images.`path`, Images.mimeType, Images.transparentBackground, Images.createdAt, Images.createdBy, Images.updatedAt, Images.updatedBy, Images.deletedAt, Images.deletedBy, Images.active FROM Images WHERE Images.id = 47124
SQL: SELECT Match_details.id, Match_details.matchId, Match_details.`date`, Match_details.matchDay, Match_details.homeScore, Match_details.awayScore, Match_details.homeScore1T, Match_details.awayScore1T, Match_details.homeScore2T, Match_details.awayScore2T, Match_details.homeScore1HT, Match_details.awayScore1HT, Match_details.homeScore2HT, Match_details.awayScore2HT, Match_details.homeScoreP, Match_details.awayScoreP, Match_details.duration, Match_details.duration1T, Match_details.duration2T, Match_details.duration1HT, Match_details.duration2HT, Match_details.hasAnalytikAvailable, Match_details.createdAt, Match_details.createdBy, Match_details.updatedAt, Match_details.updatedBy, Match_details.deletedAt, Match_details.deletedBy, Match_details.active FROM Match_details WHERE Match_details.matchId = 3115
SQL: SELECT Match_details.id, Match_details.matchId, Match_details.`date`, Match_details.matchDay, Match_details.homeScore, Match_details.awayScore, Match_details.homeScore1T, Match_details.awayScore1T, Match_details.homeScore2T, Match_details.awayScore2T, Match_details.homeScore1HT, Match_details.awayScore1HT, Match_details.homeScore2HT, Match_details.awayScore2HT, Match_details.homeScoreP, Match_details.awayScoreP, Match_details.duration, Match_details.duration1T, Match_details.duration2T, Match_details.duration1HT, Match_details.duration2HT, Match_details.hasAnalytikAvailable, Match_details.createdAt, Match_details.createdBy, Match_details.updatedAt, Match_details.updatedBy, Match_details.deletedAt, Match_details.deletedBy, Match_details.active FROM Match_details WHERE Match_details.matchId = 3115
SQL: SELECT Match_details.id, Match_details.matchId, Match_details.`date`, Match_details.matchDay, Match_details.homeScore, Match_details.awayScore, Match_details.homeScore1T, Match_details.awayScore1T, Match_details.homeScore2T, Match_details.awayScore2T, Match_details.homeScore1HT, Match_details.awayScore1HT, Match_details.homeScore2HT, Match_details.awayScore2HT, Match_details.homeScoreP, Match_details.awayScoreP, Match_details.duration, Match_details.duration1T, Match_details.duration2T, Match_details.duration1HT, Match_details.duration2HT, Match_details.hasAnalytikAvailable, Match_details.createdAt, Match_details.createdBy, Match_details.updatedAt, Match_details.updatedBy, Match_details.deletedAt, Match_details.deletedBy, Match_details.active FROM Match_details WHERE Match_details.matchId = 3115
SQL: SELECT Teams.id, Teams.createdAt, Teams.createdBy, Teams.updatedAt, Teams.updatedBy, Teams.deletedAt, Teams.deletedBy, Teams.active FROM Teams WHERE Teams.id = 88

and so on...
```

Is there any way to force Exposed to use a single query instead of multiple queries, without rewriting everything manually, with a single complex query?

Thank you, everyone!